# django test comes to a halt at test_date_length

Tags: django

I normally run tests for specific django apps, but I was curious and decided to run the entire test suite (which includes django tests) with

```
./manage.py test
```

The test suite freezes.

To find out why/where, I ran

```
./manage.py test -v 2
```

and it appears that the test stops working at

```
 test_date_length (django.contrib.auth.tests.tokens.TokenGeneratorTest) ...
```

This behavior happens for both django 1.3 and django 1.4+ (trunk).

Would appreciate any pointers on why this is happening.

Comment: I've just run the test suite just to see and I don't have this test line : `test_date_length (django.contrib.auth.tests.tokens.TokenGeneratorTest)` . Do Some apps are necessary for running this particular test ?

Comment: What platform are you on? What database are you using?

Comment: SQLite for the purpose of this test but I had the same issue using PostgreSQL yesterday as well. Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging, I discovered that this problem is a result of a Python (2.7) bug compiled by clang via MacPorts.

A loop that is executed by Python in Django code base during the execution of the TokenGeneratorTest

```
factor = 0
while True:
    factor += 1
    if i < 36 ** factor:
        factor -= 1
        break
```

hangs on Python 2.7 compiled by clang (via MacPorts).

I recompiled my Python 2.7 with apple-gcc-4.2 and this while loop no longer freezes when given a large *i* value.

Answer (score 0):

As an elaboration on the previous answer, recompile python using the instructions on http://blog.damacy.net/post/12104768819/compiling-macports-python-on-lion-using-gcc.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Apple Command Line Tools and Homebrew. This is how i fixed this error:

```
brew uninstall python
brew install --use-llvm python
```